# Legitimate change of variable in integral of an integral function?

Tags: calculus, integration, lebesgue-integral, substitution, change-of-variable

Consider the following expression:
$$ A^q=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}\left|f\left(x+y\right)g\left(x+y+Cy\right)\right|^{p}dy\right)^{q/p}dx, $$ where $1\leq p,q<\infty$, $C$ is a given invertible matrix and $f,g$ are suitable functions - in particular, such that $h(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}f\left(x+y\right)g\left(x+y+Cy\right)dy$ is well-defined. Integration shall be intendend here in Lebesgue sense. 
Two questions:

1. Is it legitimate to perform a simulatneous double change of variables, such as $$\begin{cases}
   x=u+C^{-1}v\\
   y=-C^{-1}v
   \end{cases}$$ in order to turn the inner integral into a convolution? I don't believe so, but I would like a confirmation before abandoning this way - which would be in fact very useful to prove $A<\infty$.
2. Any other general strategy in order to prove that $A<\infty$? I know that without further context this may be a vague question, but I am truly interested in finding general approaches for problems like this.

Comment: Simultaneous changes of variables are possible, but require the evaluation of a Jacobian. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant

Comment: How this applies here? This is not a "double" (= on $\mathbb{R}^(2n)$) integral, unless we a priori assume that $A<\infty$ and then apply Fubini's theorem. This is the core of my doubt: is this legitimate?

Comment: I believe no, since this would circularly assume what I am trying to prove. Furthermore, I can't see how Fubini may apply here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}A &= \left\| \left\| f(x+y)g(x+y+Cy)\right\|_{L^p(dy)} \right\|_{L^q(dx)} \end{align}
Not an answer, but the assumptions on $f,g$ need to be stronger to achieve $A<\infty$. That is, 
the finiteness of the inner norm $\left\| f(x+y)g(x+y+Cy)\right\|_{L^p(dy)}$ does not imply $A<\infty$.
To see this, let  $n=1$,$C>0$, $f(x) = e^x\mathbb 1_{x\ge 0}$ and $g(x) = e^{-x}$. Then

$$f(x+y)g(x+y+Cy)= e^{-Cy}\mathbb 1_{y \ge -x }, $$

$$ \left\| f(x+y)g(x+y+Cy)\right\|^p_{L^p(dy)} = \int_{-x}^\infty e^{-Cpy}dy = \frac{e^{Cpx}}{Cp}, $$
and yet $\exp(Cx) \notin L^q(\mathbb R)$ for any $q$.

You might want to see what happens in when $p=q$, and also when $q/p\in\mathbb Z$, as then you get repeated integrals in $y$ and a Fubini type argument may work...

Comment: Thank you for the interesting remarks. In particular, concerning the last lines: I can prove that $A<\infty$ whenever $p=q$ (as I can apply the substitution in the question), but I cannot see how to apply Fubini even in the simple case $q/p=2$. Would you further elaborate on this very promising approach? Furthermore, assuming that we can prove the result also when $q/p \in \mathbb{Z}$, is there any way to generalize it to $q/p \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Ivan for $q/p=2$, I was thinking of writing it as
$$ \int \left(\int F(x;y) dy\right)^2 dx = \iiint F(x;y_1) F(x;y_2) dx dy_1 dy_2$$
but I haven't gone any further than this thought. There may be a chance that you could interpolate $L^p$ norms? see Lemma 9 of https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/245c-notes-1-interpolation-of-lp-spaces/#more-1977 .

Comment: Thanks, the interpolation seems a very promising way. I will elaborate on the details, but I am optimistic on that.

Comment: @Ivan good luck!